# Move l l to ts/js angular file?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I need to set my logic in ts file. All logic need to be in ts file instead html. but in my situation logic is in html and i don;t know how to move to ts ?
View html :

Maybe to create any function and set logic inside ts?
Help how to do it ?

Comment: Your last edit is very weird. Why did you change the title to that and remove the code?

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of solutions to your situation:

1. Using property - In your `.ts` file use property and update it at `OnChanges` or `OrInit` lifecycle hooks.

```
export class MyComponent implements OnChanges {
  showPassenger = false;

  ngOnChanges(): void {
    this.showPassenger = this.sortFilter?.includes('PassengerPriority');
  }
}
```

2. Using [Angular pipes](https://angular.io/guide/pipes) - you can use some library like [ng-pipes](https://github.com/a8m/ng-pipes/blob/master/src/collection/contains.pipe.ts) or [implement one by yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42970354/angular-2-pipes-check-if-a-value-already-exist-in-an-array)

Comment: wait ... what is I have few parameter ? I show only 'PassengerPriority' but i have few ... I need dynamic this